# Android Studio: how to see a list of all warnings?

Tags: android, android-studio

If I change editor settings, I can see more warnings marked in yellow but I have to find and see them manually. I need a list at compilation finished, so I can click and inspect each of them.

Android studio is 2.1.1

EDIT: in particular I need to see all warnings related to minSdk changes in the app gradle script

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Answer to

> Android Studio: how to see a list of all warnings?

**Code > Inspect Code**

That will run lint and list all warnings.

Comment: yes, thank you! I made a profile with all options selected, just in case I missed something

Comment: Be warned: for large projects this could take a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't list warnings like "'when' expression on sealed classes is recommended to be exhaustive". I'm using Arctic Fox 2020 3.1. Doesn't seem to be configurable in the inspection profile either.

Comment: Update: I don't see the analyze menu anymore. It's now in Code -> Inspect Code

Answer (score -2):

For android studio you can do this way

First click to analyze in android studio like this way

[image]

second you have to inspect code this way

[image]

Comment: dont copy paste some one answers without mentioning him/her

Comment: Ok i understand.. Next time i wont do this.. pls remove down vote :)  @WaleedAsim

Comment: edit your answer and add more explanations then i will upvote

Comment: Done with your instruction. Now please upvote this :(  @WaleedAsim

Comment: Same as @malmling's answer, but with *pictures*!